# How to give .sh file read and write permission while use command "run process" in robot framework

Tags: python, automated-tests, robotframework

I have a test case needed to access a .sh file. I used 
`Run Process   ${filename}`,but it threw the error `OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied` .  I tried to put `chomod 777` before `Run Process`, but robot could not recognize it and robot took it as part of file path. Robot Anyone could help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you trying to run external commands via the  `Run process`  keyword,you have missed tab space.

`Run process   chmod   -R     777    yourfileName`